# Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^{{n-1}}\frac1{1-\frac kn}$

Tags: summation

I'm working on a problem in probability and got to the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{{n-1}}\frac1{1-\frac kn}$, where $n$ is constant.

I tried changing its form but didn't get anywhere.

Any hint?

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the index of summation.

Comment: Multiply the fraction by $n/n$ and look up "harmonic number".

Comment: @hamidkamali what do you mean?

Comment: @NormalHuman oh, that seems interesting. Thank you!

Comment: consider $\frac{1}{1-\frac{k}{n}}$ when $k=n$.

Comment: @hamidkamali okay... So the form I tried is incorrect. But the original sum is legitimate, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{1-\frac k n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac n{n-k}=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac n{m}=n\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac 1{m}=n\cdot H_n$$

Comment: I just did this, but wondering how to calculate this $H_n$. Using wikipedia for the meanwhile... Thanks anyway

Comment: As @Normal Human suggested. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: There is no closed form. But it's "roughly" $\ln n$, when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I did this after reading what he suggested

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks! This is what I was looking for